# IOstat or Pidstat not giving any information under the Headers

Tags: linux, performance-testing, windows-subsystem-for-linux, iostat

I am trying to monitor the IO usage during a Java application is executed, however, when I used iostat/vmstat/pidstat I am not seeing any information under the header, it's completely empty.

Advise me on this issue.

[pidstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnH0y.png)

[iostat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00oiS.png)

Note - I am triggering these commands in the Ubuntu app installed in Windows 10 by using WSL.

Tried updating the drivers, restarting the sysstat and re-installing the iostat and even re-installing the ubuntu nothing working.